# how to properly do EcomDev PHPUnit file upload test with $_FILES?

Tags: ecomdev-phpunit

I want to test file uploading function in my module, but i stuck with limitation of is_uploaded_file and move_uploaded_file over CLI.

Trying to emulate user uploading files actions by crafting custom $_FILES array:

```
class Company_Module_Test_Helper_CompanyHelperTests extends EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case {

       public function uploadProductImagesTest() {
            ...
            $this->assertTrue(file_exists($testFile));
            $this->assertTrue(is_readable($testFile));
            $_FILES = array(
                    ...
            );

            $this->mockSession('customer/session');
            $this->customerSession($fixtureCustomerId);
            ...
```

but when i debug, i see that move_uploaded_file in Varien_File_Uploader->_moveFile() function just return false.

I found solution to use custom namespace and override move_uploaded_file and is_uploaded_file function but when i tried to add custom namespace in test class the test won't run:

```
namespace CustomTest;   
class Company_Module_Test_Helper_CompanyHelperTests extends \EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case {
  ...
  }
```

Need some advice in this case, maybe it is possible somehow ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do actual file operations in the tests, mock `Varien_File_Uploader` instead. To be able to do so, I would create a `getUploader()` method in a helper. Then mock this helper method using the replacement feature of EcomDev_PHPUnit to let it return the mocked uploader.

Comment: Thanks you for reply, but i tried to mock the `Varien_File_Uploader` , filled it with my custom file data, and got exception in method `_setUploadFileId`:        `if (empty($_FILES)) {
            throw new Exception('$_FILES array is empty', self::TMP_NAME_EMPTY);
        }` maybe i did not fully understnad you, would be much gratituded for details. do you mean i should totally replace `Varien_File_Uploader` with my custom class (extended from `Varien_File_Uploader` for example) ?

Comment: Then you did not mock the public methods and the original methods are called. Read the mock chapter of the phpunit manual to learn more about mocking methods.